# Proxying object properties

Tags: freemarker

I am wondering, is it possible to achieve some sort of property proxying / scope inheritance in freemarker template model?
Consider this:

```
public class A {
    String aProperty;
}

public class B {
    String bProperty;
    A parent;
}
```

So in my template I could write something like `${obj.aProperty}` and it would either retrieve
`aProperty` directly from `obj` if it has one (`obj` is an instance of `A`), or retrieve `parent.aProperty` if it has none (`obj` is an instance of `B`).

The only thing that I have come up to is to use custom `BeansWrapper`, but maybe there are other, less invasive solutions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Solution with [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

```
public interface TemplateModelObject {
    String getaProperty();
}

public class BProxy implements InvocationHandler {
    private B target;

    public BProxy(B target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (method.getDeclaringClass().equals(TemplateModelObject.class)) {
            return method.invoke(target.getParent(), args);
        } else {
            return method.invoke(target, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Assume `A implements TemplateModelObject`.

```
public  class CustomWrapper extends BeansWrapper {
    public TemplateModel wrap(Object object) throws TemplateModelException {
        if (object != null && B.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
            try {
                return super.wrap(Proxy.newProxyInstance(TemplateModelObject.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{TemplateModelObject.class}, new BProxy((B) object)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new TemplateModelException(e);
            }
        } else {
            return super.wrap(object);
        }
    }
}
```

I will also need an interface declaring specific members of `B` so they can be accessed through proxy. But the main question is: won't `CustomWrapper` break something in Freemarker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this without a custom `ObjectWrapper`. After all, this is why the whole `ObjectWrapper` concept exists. The problem with this used to be that pretty much everyone wants the functionality of `BeansWrapper` and thus somehow extend that, and it often turns out that that's not so easy. Like here, my first guess is that you should override `BeanModel.get(String)` so that when it would return `null`, instead it takes the parent object, wraps it with `BeanModel.wrapper`, then delegates to the `get(String)` of that wrapped object. But it's not useful to override `get` in `BeansWrapper` directly, because it's only the superclass of the `TemplateModel` classes the `BeansWrapper` creates. Instead, you will have to override `get` in all subclasses of `BeanModel`, and then override `getModelFactory` in `BeansWrapper` (if memory server well...) so that `BeansWrapper` will create instances of your `TemplateModel` classes instead of the standard ones.

Comment: I didn`t thought that I will need to change implementation of all `BeanModel`'s too, this really complicates things a lot. Actually I think that I've found an easier solution, please see update on my question. It would be great if you could point to any potential issues concerning Freemarker.

Comment: I don't see any problem in the way you have extended `BeansWrapper` there. Note that it's slower than what I have described above, but it's surely terser.

Comment: Actually, I see a problem with that... If you `super.wrap` the proxy, and later you pass that object back to a Java method from a template, it will be unwrapped to the proxy instance, no to the original object. So the Java method that you call from the template gets the proxy instance instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it as like

Using instance of A

```
${obj.aProperty}
```

with instance of B ,

```
${obj.bProperty}

${obj.parent.aProperty} // if parent is null then you will get error
```

// so first check parent object is not null, then access it property

```
<#if obj.parent?has_content >
${obj.parent.aProperty}
</#if>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to avoid, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your basic example. The template contains a function that you pass the object to and the name of the property. It checks if the property exists, if not it get the same property form the parent. You would need to extend it for further to check if a parent exists or if you need more than one level.

A.java

```
package com.cluboramic.web.controllers;

public class A {

    private String property;

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

}
```

B.java

```
package com.cluboramic.web.controllers;

public class B {

    private String property;

    private A parent;

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public A getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(A parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

Object setup

```
A a = new A();
a.setProperty("This is A");

B b1 = new B();
b1.setParent(a);

B b2 = new B();
b2.setProperty("This is B2");
b2.setParent(a);
```

Template

```
a = ${proxyProp(a "property")},

b1 = ${proxyProp(b1 "property")},

b2 = ${proxyProp(b2 "property")}

<#--
    obj is the object to access
    property is the name of the property
-->
<#function proxyProp obj property>
    <#if obj[property]??>
        <#return obj[property]>
    <#else>
        <#return obj.parent[property]>
    </#if>
</#function>
```

Output

```
a = This is A, b1 = This is A, b2 = This is B2
```